# 400 Error Excel Macro

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to run a macro that will delete rows that don't contain a particular value in column B.  Here's my code:

```
Sub deleteRows()
    Dim count As Integer
    count = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(Range("AF:AF"))
    Dim i As Integer
    i = 21
    Do While i <= count
        If (Application.WorksheetFunction.IsNumber(Application.WorksheetFunction.Search("OSR Platform", Range("B" & i))) = False) Then
            If (Application.WorksheetFunction.IsNumber(Application.WorksheetFunction.Search("IAM", Range("B" & i))) = False) Then
                Rows(i).EntireRow.Delete
                i = i - 1
                count = count - 1
            End If
        End If
        i = i + 1
    Loop
End Sub
```

Now what it SHOULD be doing is the following:

1.) Find the number of rows to go through and set that as count (this works)

2.) Start at row 21 and look for "OSR Platform" and "IAM" in column B [this kind of works  (see below)]

3.) If it finds neither, delete the entire row and adjust the count and row number as necessary (this works)

For some reason, whenever the code gets to the first If statement, an error window with a red X pops up that just says "400."  As far as I can tell, I have written everything syntactically soundly, but clearly there's something wrong.

Comment: No that's not the problem.  I've tested this method with other conditions on the If statement and it works just fine.  Good thought, though.

Comment: @Gaffi - came here to suggest the same thing

Comment: Just in case, I just tried what Gaffi had suggested (that I start at the bottom of the table and loop backwards) and I got the same error.

Comment: @JackRadcliffe After my first comment, I thought there was more to add, so I've put all of it into an answer below, if it helps.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You may want to start by looping the other way. When you delete a line, all the previous lines are shifted. You account for this, but a reverse loop is simpler (*for me anyways*) to understand than keeping track of when I've offset the current position within the loop:

`For i = count To 21 Step -1`

Also, you're relying too much on `Application.WorksheetFunction`:

`(Application.WorksheetFunction.IsNumber(Application.WorksheetFunction.Search("OSR Platform", Range("B" & i))) = False)`

to

`InStr(Range("B" & i).value, "OSR Platform") > 0`

`Application.WorksheetFunction` takes much more processing power, and depending on what you are trying to accomplish, this can take a significantly longer amount of time. Also for this suggested change, the code size is reduced and becomes easier to read without it.

Your `count` can also be obtained without `A.WF`:

- Excel 2000/03: `count = Range("AF65536").End(xlUp).Row`
- Excel 2007/10: `count = Range("AF1048576").End(xlUp).Row`
- Version independent: `count = Range("AF" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row`

One more thing is that you can do (and *should* do in this case) is combine your `If` statements into one.

Making these changes, you end up with:

```
Sub deleteRows()
    Dim count As Integer
    count = Range("AF" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    Dim i As Integer
    For i = count To 21 Step -1
        If Len(Range("B" & i).value) > 0 Then
            If InStr(Range("B" & i).value, "OSR Platform") > 0 Or InStr(Range("B" & i).value, "IAM") > 0 Then
                Range("B" & i).Interior.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0)
            End If
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```

If this does not help, then can you step through the code line by line. Add a breakpoint, and step through with <kbd>F8</kbd>. Highlight the variables in your code, right-click, choose "add Watch...", click "OK", ([Here's an excellent resource to help you with your debugging in general](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/debug.htm)) and note the following:

- Which line hits the error?
- What is the value of `i` and `count` when that happens? (add a watch on these variables to help)

Comment: I have a couple comments.  First, shouldn't the second InStr be `InStr("IAM", Range("B" & i).value) = 0`?  Second, what's the problem with relying on `Application.WorksheetFunction`?

Comment: Er, you're right about the `InStr`, that was my typo. `Application.WorksheetFunction` takes much more processing power, and depending on what you are trying to accomplish, this can take a significantly longer amount of time.

Comment: I see.  Well unfortunately, what you've suggested does not work but I know why.  The cells that either do or do not contain "OSR Platform" and "IAM" are merged over a few rows, so not all of the rows I need to be deleted are deleted.  I've tried to avert this by instead of deleting the row, changing that cell's color so I at least have SOMETHING to go by.  But when I do `If InStr(...) > 0 Or InStr(...) > 0 Then Range("B" & i).Interior.Color = 35536`, it changes the color of every cell instead of just the ones with "OSR Platform" or "IAM" as I expected.  Any idea why?

Comment: I did the `Or` because as I inferred, doesn't `InStr` return a number greater than 0 if the selection is found within the cell?  And so if either is found, I want to highlight it.

Comment: @JackRadcliffe By the looks of your original code, (nested `If`s) you were looking for both together. Your code `If InStr(...) > 0 Or InStr(...) > 0` should be correct then. I'll suggest again that you step through and watch the variables. When your loop hits a line that should not be marked, see what those `InStr` checks are returning.

Comment: When debugging, how do I see the values of the variables?

Comment: Scratch that--I figured it out.  The debugging question, that is.

Comment: Highlight the variable in your code, right-click, choose "add Watch...", click "OK".  [Here's an excellent resource to help you with your debugging in general](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/debug.htm)

Comment: Great, thanks.  So I've found that when the cell it's looking in is completely blank, `InStr` is returning 1, and whenever there's any text (whether it contains "OSR Platform" or not), `InStr` returns 0.  Any idea why this would be the case?

Comment: I see the same. My suggestion is then to add another `If` check. I'm updating the answer. Also, this does not take into account case. i.e. `"IAM"` `!=`/`<>` `"iAm"`, if you have any inconsistency there.

Comment: You're saying that case doesn't matter, right?  Either way, there is no variation.

Comment: Also, I added another `If`: `Range("B" & i).Value <> ""`

Comment: String case *DOES* matter; The `InStr` will try to match on correct case.

Comment: Okay.  Either way, it's looking for "OSR Platform" within a cell that reads "OSR Platform Upgrade >> EP OSR Hypercare Support" and it's still returning 0.

Comment: That is very odd, but I am seeing the same. Will your searches (`"OSR Platform"` and `"IAM"`) always be the leading characters? If so you could check `If Left(Range("B" & i).Value, 12) = "OSR Platform" Or Left(Range("B" & i).Value, 3) = "IAM" Then` ...but that doesn't explain why `InStr` is not working as expected.

Comment: OSR Platform will always be first, but unfortunately IAM will not... Anyways, I appreciate your effort and will try to find a different way to look for "IAM."  Thanks!

Comment: Sorry it wasn't a perfect example, but I'm glad I could help.

Comment: You should be using `Range("AF" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row` to make the count version-independent.

Comment: You're right, @JimmyPena, but I also like to identify what that value is so potential errors are more apparent. I'll update the answer.

Comment: The issue with InStr is likely because it does a string comparison and an empty cell is a problem. Append a " " like this                        If InStr("OSR Platform", Range("B" & i).Value & " ") > 0 which actually lets it look in a string for the pattern and you will see a different result. Also I would Dim these as Longs rather than Integers

Comment: @datatoo I tried this trick with my code and the `InStr` still did not correctly match on (e.g. "OSR Platform 123"). Actually, I found that even a correct match from before, (e.g. "IAM") did not match with this change. In playing with this more, I've discovered that I'm a bit slow today. There is a problem with the `InStr` syntax, which I'm correcting above...

Comment: Sorry I missed this too, actually the InStr function should have the String to look IN first, and the string looked FOR second  InStr(Range("B" & i).Value &" ", "OSR Platform")

Answer (score 3):

This worked for me. It uses AutoFilter, does not require looping or worksheet functions.

```
Sub DeleteRows()

Dim currentSheet As Excel.Worksheet
Dim rngfilter As Excel.Range
Dim lastrow As Long, lastcolumn As Long

Set currentSheet = ActiveSheet

' get range
lastrow = currentSheet.Cells(Excel.Rows.Count, "AF").End(xlUp).Row
lastcolumn = currentSheet.Cells(1, Excel.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
Set rngfilter = currentSheet.Range("A1", currentSheet.Cells(lastrow, lastcolumn))

' filter by column B criteria
rngfilter.AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:="<>*OSR Platform*", Operator:= _
        xlAnd, Criteria2:="<>*IAM*"

' delete any visible row greater than row 21 which does not meet above criteria
rngfilter.Offset(21).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).EntireRow.Delete

' remove autofilter arrows
currentSheet.AutoFilterMode = False
End Sub
```

This code applies AutoFilter to column B to see which rows contain neither "OSR Platform" nor "IAM" in column B. Then it simply deletes the remaining rows greater than 21. Test it on a copy of your workbook first.

With a huge nod to [this OzGrid](http://www.ozgrid.com/forum/showthread.php?t=153994) thread, because I can never remember the proper syntax for selecting visible cells after filtering.

Comment: +1 Since this also works with the merged cells noted by the OP.

Comment: @Gaffi LOL I didn't know there were merged cells!